# Do rogue levels count toward your Familiar's special abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, rogue, familiars

The writing on [Familiars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) says:

> All familiars have special abilities (or impart abilities to their masters) depending on the master's combined level in classes that grant familiars.

Since the rogue class can grant a familiar, does that count?

Answer (score 5):

The wording is "that grant familiars," not "that *can* grant familiars." Rogue counts as a class that grants a familiar *if and only if* you actually take the familiar talent, and then it only adds (*rogue level* − 4) to the combined level for the purpose of your familiar’s benefits.